# hibernate only saves the first object from the list

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, spring-boot

i have two entity classes named Qa.java and Answeres.java

my Qa entity consists of lists of answers.

**Qa.Java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "qa")
public class Qa {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "id")
private int id;
private String question;
private String type;
private String description;
private String param;
private int maxlength;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "qa", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
private List<Answers> answersList = new ArrayList<>();

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getQuestion() {
    return question;
}

public void setQuestion(String question) {
    this.question = question;
}

public String getType() {
    return type;
}

public void setType(String type) {
    this.type = type;
}

public String getDescription() {
    return description;
}

public void setDescription(String description) {
    this.description = description;
}

public String getParam() {
    return param;
}

public void setParam(String param) {
    this.param = param;
}

public int getMaxlength() {
    return maxlength;
}

public void setMaxlength(int maxlength) {
    this.maxlength = maxlength;
}

public List<Answers> getAnswersList() {
    return answersList;
}

public void setAnswersList(List<Answers> answersList) {
    this.answersList = answersList;
}
}
```

**Answers.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "answers")
public class Answers {


@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private int id;
private String ans_label;
private int ans_value;
private int ans_weightage;
private int is_default;

@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "question_id", referencedColumnName = "id",nullable = false)
private Qa qa;

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getAns_label() {
    return ans_label;
}

public void setAns_label(String ans_label) {
    this.ans_label = ans_label;
}

public int getAns_value() {
    return ans_value;
}

public void setAns_value(int ans_value) {
    this.ans_value = ans_value;
}

public int getAns_weightage() {
    return ans_weightage;
}

public void setAns_weightage(int ans_weightage) {
    this.ans_weightage = ans_weightage;
}

public int getIs_default() {
    return is_default;
}

public void setIs_default(int is_default) {
    this.is_default = is_default;
}

public Qa getQa() {
    return qa;
}

public void setQa(Qa qa) {
    this.qa = qa;
}
}
```

My controller from where i am trying to insert data.

**TableDataController.java**

```
@Controller
public class TabletDataController {

@Autowired
QaRepository qaRepository;

@RequestMapping(value = "/saveApiData", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public void saveApiData(){
    Qa qa = new Qa();
    qa.setParam("");
    qa.setType("input_spinner");
    qa.setDescription("");
    qa.setQuestion("व्यक्तिको पहिलो नाम  ?");

    ArrayList<Answers> answersArrayList = new ArrayList<>();

    Answers answers = new Answers();
    answers.setAns_label("नेपाली");
    answers.setAns_value(1);
    answers.setAns_weightage(0);
    answers.setIs_default(0);

    Answers answers1 = new Answers();
    answers1.setAns_label("english");
    answers1.setAns_value(2);
    answers1.setAns_weightage(2);
    answers1.setIs_default(2);

    Answers answers2 = new Answers();
    answers2.setAns_label("japense");
    answers2.setAns_value(3);
    answers2.setAns_weightage(3);
    answers2.setIs_default(3);

    answersArrayList.add(answers);
    answersArrayList.add(answers1);
    answersArrayList.add(answers2);

    qa.setAnswersList(answersArrayList);
    answers.setQa(qa);
    qaRepository.save(qa);

    }
    }
```

my qaRepository extends JpaRepository. so whenever i call this api only first object i.e

```
   Answers answers = new Answers();
   answers.setAns_label("नेपाली");
   answers.setAns_value(1);
   answers.setAns_weightage(0);
   answers.setIs_default(0);
```

is saved. how can i saved all the given list?

Answer (score 1):

You have to set the qa object to answers1 and answers2 objects as well and not just for the answers object.